# How to pick the values from two co-related dropdown in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

In my case, there are two drop down mainly displaying cities & branches,

suppose I select City1 from select city drop down then select branch showing Branch10, branch11, branch13 values.

Suppose i select City2 from select city drop down then select branch Drop down showing Branch20, branch21, branch23 values.

Now i want to select Random city from first DropDown & Random branch but corresponding to selected city bucket.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

While you have selected any city from City dropdown then there must be a ajax call generated during recording of your script.

So first of all correlate value for city from previous responses and store into one variable, let say City and pass match number as 0 in regular expression extractor for selecting random values, now pass this city into the request as `${city}` and in response you must be getting options for branch (depending upon the city which you have entered) now corelate this also and pass match no. as 0 and use it in following requests.

Comment: thanks for answer, more information about handling Ajax calls?

Comment: is your issue resolved or are you still struggling with the same challenge?

Comment: I am looking for best solution, currently i have done same by means Bean shell processor but its not looking best solution. you have more idea then share dude.

Comment: The way which i have mentioned in my answer, you can use that one to get your work done and there will be no need of writing any beanshell and that would be the best solution as per your requirement.